# Anaerobic Fungal or Plant life

Tags: biology, flora, underground

The Dark Warlock Susie has heard of a [cave system with a lethal density of argon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/127715/argon-environment-spelunking) that is protecting a burgeoning monster population. In the interest of beefing up her security, Susie wants to recreate the underground environment near her magical spire. However some of the monsters are non-carnivores and she cannot figure out what they consume without leaving the cave nor killing off outside plant life by digging into their roots. Also, even warlocks fear creating new life and would prefer using something already in existence.

Assuming a hunter-gatherer mentality, where the food organisms are encouraged to grow but are not [cultivated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultivation). What would be the primary [anaerobic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_organism) food stuff that actively grows for non-carnivores in a light deprived environment?

The environment can be altered in any way except it must contain [1% or less oxygen in the air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoxia_(environmental)), the argon is not a concern here. Susie is only a Dark Warlock after all!

Comment: Similar: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94136/how-would-giant-secluded-underground-cave-dwelling-insects-get-enough-food

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that the bottom of the food chain would have to be bacteria that gets its energy from chemicals (like around the thermal vents in the deep ocean).  There would have to be enough water and heat to make this work.  Any air would likely to be very hot moist.

So you would need to create or move a geothermal vent to where you want your magical spire (or build the spire where you find such an underground vent).

The air will probably end up being a pretty high pressure too since there will likely be gasses mixed in with the mineral rich hot water and you don't want too many vents to the outside or you will lose your argon.

Comment: This is a great start and having a thermal vent to add energy to the system will be good for creating ideal humidity for things that could be fed on like Peat Moss or Neocallimastigomycota which are both anaerobic.